# How to make Hadoop reducer output multiple values for a single key

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have some dataset and I want to calculate the minimum, maximum and average for each record (for example: userID_1 -- minimum_1-- maximum_1 -- avg).

this my code, I need to know what to do that can let me write those values for that single key:

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        int visitsCounter = 0;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        float avg;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            int currentValue = val.get();
            sum += currentValue;
            visitsCounter++;
            min = Math.min(min, currentValue);
            max = Math.max(max, currentValue);
        }
        avg = sum / visitsCounter;

        //here can be the supposed edit to let me output (user - min - max - avg )
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In MapReduce,** data flows in terms of Key-Value pairs at both phases i.e., **Map Phase and Reduce Phase.**

So we need to design our **Key-Value pairs** at Map Level and Reduce Level.

Here key and value data types are Writables.

**Key can be composed of multiple values and value can be composed of multiple values.**

For atomic values case, we use IntWritable, DoubleWritable, LongWritable, FloatWritable etc...

For complex key and value data cases, we use **Text** data type or **user defined data types**.

**Simple solution** to handle this scenario is use **Text** data type i.e., concatenation of all these columns into a String object and serialize this String object into Text object. But this is **inefficient** due to a lot of String concatenations on **large data sets**.

Use custom/user defined data type to handle this kind of scenario.
Write the **Custom data type using Writable or WritableComparable** interface from **Hadoop API**.

```java
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Text> {
    Text emitValue = new Text()
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        int visitsCounter = 0;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        float avg;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            int currentValue = val.get();
            sum += currentValue;
            visitsCounter++;
            min = Math.min(min, currentValue);
            max = Math.max(max, currentValue);
        }
        avg = sum / visitsCounter;
        String myValue = min + "\t" + max + "\t" + avg;
        emitValue.set(myValue);
        //here can be the supposed edit to let me output (user - min - max - avg )
        context.write(key, emitValue);
    }
}
```